# Reaching to control bychanged value in Asp.net repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have an interesting question. I have a repeater on my page:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rpt" OnItemDataBound="rpt_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblRptKey" Text='<%#Eval("ID")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="Hidden1" ClientIDMode="Static" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %></label>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div class="media">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="ex1SliderVal" CssClass="pull-right" Font-Bold="true">5</asp:Label>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="ex1" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="10" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="5" data-slider-handle="square" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

and I am changing IDs of some controls in ItemDataBound event of repeater, which is necessary for my javascript functions. They should be different from eachother.

```
protected void rpt_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        var input = e.Item.FindControl("ex1");
        input.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
        input.ID = "ex" + (e.Item.ItemIndex + 1).ToString();
        var label = e.Item.FindControl("ex1SliderVal");
        label.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
        label.ID = "ex" + (e.Item.ItemIndex + 1).ToString() + "SliderVal";
        var hidden = e.Item.FindControl("Hidden1");
        hidden.ID = "Hidden" + (e.Item.ItemIndex + 1).ToString();
    }
```

Here is the question part. I cant reach the HiddenFields' values by IDs which I changed before.

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NHibernateDaoFactory DaoFactory=new NHibernateDaoFactory();
        SportType_User stu = new SportType_User();
        stu.User = loginUser;
        stu.SportType=DaoFactory.GetSportTypeDao().GetById(Convert.ToInt32(lblKey.Text),false);
        foreach (RepeaterItem item in rpt.Items)
        {
            Label lblRptKey = (Label)item.FindControl("lblRptKey");
            int ProfessionId=Convert.ToInt32(lblRptKey.Text);
            Profession profession = DaoFactory.GetProfessionDao().GetById(ProfessionId,false);
            HiddenField hidden = (HiddenField)item.FindControl("Hidden"+(item.ItemIndex+1).ToString());//This is returning right for first. But then it is returning null
            int val = Convert.ToInt32(hidden.Value);
            val = val > 10 ? 10 : (val < 0 ? 0 : val);
            ProfessionValue pv = new ProfessionValue();
            pv.Profession = profession;
            pv.Value = val;
            stu.ProfessionValues.Add(pv);
        }
        stu.SelfValued = true;
        DaoFactory.GetSportType_UserDao().Save(stu);
        Response.Redirect("EditSports.aspx");
    }
```

Hidden field in the method above is returning right for first item but then it is returning null

Comment: What is you error? And are you *sure* you need to manually change the ID's? What are the ID's on the client side if you eliminate that?

Comment: I edited the question. And yeah I am sure that I need to change IDs because of my javascript implementation. Clientside IDs are the same as IDs. I did it static

Comment: have you tried not changing the IDs but setting a unique class name to use on your clientside code?

Comment: Yeah I did that as a solution.